# Undoable enchancer for combined reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

For example I have two reducers (todos and visibilityFilter) and I want to make all of them undoable.

This code will give an error:

```
var undoableCombinedReducer = undoable(
  combineReducers({
    todos,
    visibilityFilter
  }), 
  {
    filter: distinctState()
  }
);
```

Is it possible to wrap combined reducer into `undoable` enhancer at once without wrapping each low level reducer?

Comment: What error are you getting? What you have looks fine assuming all of the referenced variables behave like their name suggests.

Comment: Sorry. All works. The error was in my app. I should use `state.present.todos` instead of `state.todos`